# Tokens mismatch when submitting form

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I am currently facing a problem with my form submission. All works fine on my development environment but started giving issues when It was deployed online. Any form submission triggers a 419 error which on debugging, I found out that the generated `_token` input from the submitted form differs from the session token (`$request->session()->token()`) which is quite strange considering It worked perfectly on my development environment. My theory is that it should have something to do with session but I'm not sure how.

My form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```

I was able to see in `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware that `$request->input('_token')` and `$request->session()->token()` differ which causes it to throw a `TokenMismatchException` error

Anyone knows what's going on here

Comment: check to make sure your sessions are working correctly (often can be a cookie problem)

Comment: please check if you give proper permissions tp the storage and bootstrap/cache folders.

Comment: clear cache on the server, use the following commands.

php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear

Comment: I can see where the problem is coming fro now. The app is running via kubernetes pods and It turns out that the pods create multiple cache keys kind of a race condition. So how to make the keys same accross the pods ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was coming from different app keys being used in the pods running the app. This caused the session and cache keys to differ. Using same `APP_KEY` between the apps solved the issue. I generated the key on my local and copied it to the server `.env` files. Thanks everyone for your help.